# Price Book Record Types

Tags: record-type, pricebook

Is it possible to have Price Books associated to different record types and assign these record types to specific profiles in order to have a refined list of price books available to only certain profile types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how Record Types work. Record Types do not *restrict access* to records, they merely stop users from creating records with those record types, or changing existing records to that record type (i.e. you'd be restricting users to which type of Price Book they can create or change to, which is clearly not your intent).

Instead, you can set the Organization Wide Defaults to No Access, then go to each individual Price Book and share them using the Sharing button. You can share by user, public group, or role hierarchy, but not by profile.

It would be technically feasible to produce code that generates public groups and group membership based on their profile, if you wanted to, but that's really outside the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: This answered my question exactly. I knew about the sharing and OWD but I was not aware that this wouldnt work with Profiles. Work around was to add each user to the Manual Sharing settings on the desired price book. Much appreciation